# error: "cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Our site need bot to work, this is only error left I got "cannot read property ´value´ of undefined ". I have set bind_address to 0.0.0.0 ( I have tried my ip and site ip, but no help). On phpmyadmin I have set every permission to this ip. In console its says that theres problem in js file line 488. I hope someone can help with this.

```
var mysqlInfo;
mysqlInfo = {
host       : ´x.x.x.x´
user       : ´root´
password   : ´xxxxx´
database   : ´mysql´
charset    : ´utf8_general_ci´
};
```

Here is line 488

```
if(offer.items_to_receive.length > row[0].value) {
```

Comment: Then `row[0]` isn't set. You have to add more code

Comment: Use a `console.log` statement and view what row is.What is `row`? Are you certain it's an array of objects that has a property value?

Comment: can you check the length of `row`?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c2fd7542a389b965b62841545dbd7ba5 There is hole code of that line 488.

Answer (score 0):

First item in row is not defined or the row is an empty array.

Comment: gyazo.com/c2fd7542a389b965b62841545dbd7ba5 There is hole code of that line 488.